# How to delete google/facebook user from firebase auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

As described in [firebase auth document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user) to delete a user account, one needs to re-authenticate the user and then perform the delete operation.

If the user has sign-in using firebase auth, we can use `EmailAuthProvider.credential(email,password);`
to get the credential and pass it to `reauthenticateWithCredential`.

But what about the user that authenticated using a social provider like Google, and Facebook?

GoogleAuthProvider need tokenId, or accessToken to return credential, but I'm not sure if the credential should be passed to `reauthenticateWithCredential`

```
      const tokenId = currentUser?.refreshToken;
      const googleCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(tokenId);
```

Comment: Think a bit. If someone has access to your computer, he could delete your account in seconds. That why you cannot delete account when authenticated using providers. Deleting account cannot be easy.